# How can i use my function a_c_t_b()

Tags: python, function

**My code looks like:**

```
def g_b():
    items_in_bag = []
    done=False
    bugout_bag = 'Bug Out Bag'
    while done == False:
        item = input('What bags do you have? [Enter x to stop]')
        items_in_bag.append(item)
        if item == 'x':
            done = True
            items_in_bag.remove('x')
            break
        else:
            continue

    items_in_bag.append(bugout_bag)
    print("Your bags\n")
    print(items_in_bag)
    return items_in_bag

def g_c():
    coins_in_bag = []
    done=False
    while done == False:
        coin_item = input('What coins do you have? [Enter x to stop]')
        if coin_item == 'x':
            done = True
            break
        else:
            coins_in_bag.append(coin_item)
            continue
    print("Your coins\n")
    print(coins_in_bag)
    return coins_in_bag


def a_c_t_b(items_in_bag, coins_in_bag):
    #print('Here are your coins:\n')
    #g_c()
    #print('Here are your bags:\n')
    #print(items_in_bag)
    print (items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)
    return (items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)

def main():
    g_b()
    g_c()
    a_c_t_b(items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)

main()
```

However, when i run this code like: `import myfile`

It gives me an error of:

```
  File ".\myfile.py", line 51, i
    a_c_t_b(items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)
NameError: global name 'items_in_bag' is not defined
```

I'm simply  trying to return the values of `items_in_bag,coins_in_bag` from their respective `functions`.

Thank you

Comment: What is up with those function names? Anyway, you're just calling functions and throwing away the result. You have to actually save references to things if you want to reuse them. Naming a local variable in a function doesn't automatically have global effects like you think it does.

Comment: You would probably benefit from the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call your functions more sensible names.

To answer your question, your `g_b` and `g_c` functions return values, they don't return names. At the point where you call `a_c_t_b`, Python has no idea what `items_in_bag` is, because yo'uve never defined it. Python can't know you mean "the value returned from `g_b`": you have to tell it.

```
items_in_bag = g_b()
coins_in_bag = g_c()
a_c_t_b(items_in_bag, coins_in_bag)
```

Comment: I'll tell you, your comments are amazing on this site, i've learned a lot from you @Daniel - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `g_b` and `g_c` but never catching their returned values.

You can either do:

```
def main():
    items_in_bag = g_b()
    coins_in_bag = g_c()
    a_c_t_b(items_in_bag, coins_in_bag)
```

or:

```
def main():
        a_c_t_b(g_b(), g_c())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import the module `main` function is executed (call in last line). And `main` function use undefined identifiers `items_in_bag` and `coins_in_bag`:

```
def main():
    g_b()
    g_c()
    a_c_t_b(items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)
```

Probably you want something like

```
def main():
    items_in_bag = g_b()
    coins_in_bag = g_c()
    a_c_t_b(items_in_bag,coins_in_bag)
```